# Почему листенер не распространяется на все кнопки в цикле?

Tags: java

Отрывок кода:

```
JButton b[];    
for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
    b[i] = new JButton();
    b[i].addActionListener(this);
    b[i].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    pane.add(b[i]);
}
```

ActionListener срабатывает только при нажатии на кнопку *b[0]* , на остальные не реагирует. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: сам интерфейс ActionListener внутри этого же класса находится

Comment: Подозреваю, что ошибка где-то в другом месте

Comment: В приведенном коде нет ничего, что объясняло бы описываемое поведение.